# Synergy locks up Windows 7 when Visual Studio is debugging

Tags: windows-7, synergy, visual-studio-2008

I use Synergy (running as administrator) to go through two x64 Windows 7 machines (with all flavors of Visual studio from 2003 to 2010 professional) and an MacOS 10.6 desktop and most of the time it works flawlessly.

However, if I happen to be in the middle of a transition from one Windows 7 machine to the other (it's never happened to the Mac but I don't flip to it that often) when Visual Studio hits a breakpoint, the mouse and keyboard both completely lock up and the only way I can seem to do anything is to physically unplug the mouse and keyboard and plug them back in. Unfortunately I have to crawl under my desk to do that, so you can see where it'd be annoying.

Anybody have any idea how I can get around this?

I did note that it was much more frequent with the previous version I had of Synergy+ before I upgraded/sidegraded to the current version of Synergy. But it's still happening.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? It's the only bad thing about Synergi - I use Visual Studio all day so this is a real pain.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me all the time, too.  The only work around I've found that doesn't require crawling under my desk is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, select switch user, and log back in.  This will move the mouse and keyboard focus back to the synergy server, but transitions to other screens won't work until you close the debugger.

Comment: How does this help? You can get it to work by focusing on any window other than Visual Studio, but that is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a possible work around is in the server configuration, "Advanced server settings", "Options", set the "Don't take foreground window on Windows servers" check box.

Comment: Yes! Seems to work!